# Не отображается SVG после запуска приложения

Tags: c#, wpf

Проблема заключается в том, что мои svg картинки видны в WPF приложение, но при запуске по какой-то причине они пропадают. Так как WPF напрямую не поддерживает SVG, приходится использовать сторонние библиотеки, в моем случае SharpVectors.

```
xmlns:svgc="http://sharpvectors.codeplex.com/svgc/"
...
<svgc:SvgViewbox Source="/Resources/Images/cookies.svg" Width="55" />
```

Буду рад услышать, как по-другому можно внедрять svg в wpf приложение!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: SVG легко конвертируется в XAML. А картинки могут пропадать, потому что путь к ним у вас неправильно задан. Корневой каталог при работе приложения и при работе в дизайнере - разные.

Comment: @aepot, да, действильно, конвертация SVG в XAML помогла!Благодарю)